# Calculating the median of a time series, by 8 every 8 hours

Tags: r, time, time-series, mean

I am new to R and I do have to calculate the mean of  time series, containing 5 years, with hourly taken data of ozon etc..

My df looks like:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "01.01.2010", class = "factor"), 
day.of = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), time = structure(1:4, .Label = c("00:00", 
"01:00", "02:00", "03:00"), class = "factor"), SVF_Ray = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), Gmax = c(0, 0, 0, 0), Ta = c(-1.3, -1.2, -1.2, 
-1.2), Tmrt = c(-19.3, -12.1, -12, -12.1), PET = c(-10.4, 
-8.7, -8.7, -8.7), PT = c(-11.3, -9.3, -9.3, -9.3), Ozon = c(61.35, 
62.65, 63.4, 63.85), rDatum = structure(c(14610, 14610, 14610, 
14610), class = "Date"), year = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010), 
month = c(1, 1, 1, 1), day = c(1, 1, 1, 1), hour = c(0, 1, 
2, 3)), .Names = c("date", "day.of", "time", "SVF_Ray", "Gmax", 
"Ta", "Tmrt", "PET", "PT", "Ozon", "rDatum", "year", "month", 
"day", "hour"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to calculate the mean of Ozon every 8 hours, so a series of 4 calculated means for every day. I have arranged my datum like:

```
Datum_Ozon$rDatum <- as.Date(data$date, format="%d.%m.%Y")

Datum_Ozon$hour<-as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$time), ":"))[seq(1, 2 * length(df$time), 2)])
```

Format is numeric

But I don't know any further in achieving my goal. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is more useful to give a (portion) of your data with dput(DF_Ozone) than a picture of the data

Comment: thanks for your comment, I am trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Also it is difficult to give an answer if we don't know what type of data `time` is. However, assuming it is some sort of time object, you can use `ifelse` to set some conditions (i.e. chunks of 8 hours) to create a new grouping variable.

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont know how to upload a part of my df, I know it would be helpful.

Comment: thnak you, hope I did it right

Comment: Not exactly perfect. You need to assign dput a name so that answer can reference the dataframe. In my answer I named it `df`. Also slightly problematically, your `dput` data only has four hours of data. The example still works but without at least one 24 period, the utility of the example may be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its the case that your data is regular and complete (ie, every hour has a record), the following base R code should do the trick:

```
# Get the number of 8 hour intervals
intervalCnt <- nrow(df) / 8L

# add a grouping vector to your data
df$group <- rep(1:intervalCnt, each=8)

# get the median for each interval, keep year var around for later
intervalMedian <- aggregate(var~group + day + month + year, data=df, FUN=median)
```

Note that this solution relies on the assumption that the data has a regular structure, i.e., every hour has a record. If the measure of interest is missing, i.e. NA, then simply adding na.rm to the aggregate function will return the statistics of interest:

```
# get the median for each interval
intervalMedian <- aggregate(var~group + day + month + year, data=df, FUN=median, na.rm=T)
```

If you have a variable for hour of the day, here is a simple way to check for data regularity:

```
table(df$hourOfDay)
```

The result of this function is a frequency count of each hour. The counts should be equal. Another thing to check is that the first observation starts in the hour following the final observation, i.e. if the hour of observation 1 == "00:00", then the hour of the final observation should be 23:00.

To provide a plot of the mean of the 8 hour periods by year, you can again use aggregate:

```
intervalMeans.year <- aggregate(var~group, data=intervalMedian,
                                FUN=mean, na.rm=T)
```

The inclusion of the group, day, month, and year variables in the intervalMedian data.frame allow for a lot of different aggregations. For example, with a minor adjustment, it is possible to get the average value of a variable over the 5 year period for each time period-day-month:

```
intervalMedian$periodDay <- rep(1:3, length.out=intervalMedian)
intervalMeans.dayMonthPeriod <- aggregate(var~periodDay+day+month,
                                          data=intervalMedian, FUN=mean, na.rm=T)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach, as you mention, is that often data is not complete. This approach would carry on happily and you'd have no way of knowing that your interval and being assigned incorrectly.

Comment: indeed, my data is sadly not complete, there are many hours with NA

Comment: @boshek this is a matter of data structure. Sometimes it is complete and sometimes it isn't. when the data is not regular, then this option won't work. When it is regular, this is a very straightforward solution. It is up to the analyst to understand their data before implementing a solution. If, as the OP posted above, the data is regular in structure, event though values are missing, this will work as long as the na.rm argument is set to TRUE.

Comment: @lmo I agree completely with everything you say and am just pointing out that for a beginner you really need to be careful or as you say "understand their data before implementing a solution"

Comment: @boshek I agree with your note of caution. I've added a couple of quick checks that the OP could use in order to greatly reduce some main sources of unnoticed irregularities.

Comment: I tried this solution, and it looks like it is working. Also I have tested my data as you mentioned. It looks fine! Thank you!

Comment: My last step would be, to show this data in a graph with x = day of year (1-365) and y should be the 8h median of the Ozone. Any idea? Could I aggregate it to my former df?

Comment: @Joe.b. what level of aggregation is the graph? are you aggregating 8 hour periods across years? or across days within a year?

Comment: @Imo, the data (the means of the 8 hours) should be used of the whole 5 year period. the graph should aggregate the 5year period of the 8 hour means for 365 days, e.g. 8 hour mean of day of year 1, 8 hour mean day of year 2 and so on.

Comment: @Joe.b I modified the code to allow for the figure I believe that you want. The earlier `aggregate` function now includes year, which allows for aggregation by year in the final line of code.

Comment: @Imo, I used your new code to create my new df, the graph I get is the total graph of the data of the 5 years. It creates a graph with a frequency of 5 years. What I want is just a curve for Ozone, that looks like a normal distribution of the 5 years, aggregated for one year. Got what I mean, sorry that I cant express myself in a better way, but thanks a lot for your help! ;)

Comment: @Joe.b A bit of clarification: is an observation a year-8hour-day combination, so there would be ~365 (calendar days) * 5 (years) * 3 (8 hour periods) observations? Or is it a calendar day-8 hour period, so you would have ~365 (calendar days) * 3 (8 hour periods)?

Comment: @Imo, its like you mentioned first. 5 year period. 1 hour observation. Now I have calculated the 8 hour mean of this whole period. So if i plo this data now, I have an alternating graph, 5 peaks. What I need is just one graph that looks like a normal distribution (of course its not one), just to clearify. So the 5 years should form a one year graph, based on the collected data.

Comment: @Joe.b Hopefully, the above modification does what you are looking for. I kept a number of variables (day, month, year) and showed a simple method using `rep` that should be useful in constructing whatever aggregation you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example using a `dplyr` pipe rather than a `plyr` approach as well as `ifelse()`. Everything is self contained here:

```
library(dplyr)

## OP data
df <- 
structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "01.01.2010", class = "factor"), 
day.of = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), time = structure(1:4, .Label = c("00:00", 
"01:00", "02:00", "03:00"), class = "factor"), SVF_Ray = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), Gmax = c(0, 0, 0, 0), Ta = c(-1.3, -1.2, -1.2, 
-1.2), Tmrt = c(-19.3, -12.1, -12, -12.1), PET = c(-10.4, 
-8.7, -8.7, -8.7), PT = c(-11.3, -9.3, -9.3, -9.3), Ozon = c(61.35, 
62.65, 63.4, 63.85), rDatum = structure(c(14610, 14610, 14610, 
14610), class = "Date"), year = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010), 
month = c(1, 1, 1, 1), day = c(1, 1, 1, 1), hour = c(0, 1, 
2, 3)), .Names = c("date", "day.of", "time", "SVF_Ray", "Gmax", 
"Ta", "Tmrt", "PET", "PT", "Ozon", "rDatum", "year", "month", 
"day", "hour"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

df %>%
  mutate(DayChunk=ifelse(hour %in% c(0:7),"FirstThird",
         ifelse(hour %in% c(8:15), "SecondThird"
              ,"ThirdThird")
         )) %>%
  group_by(Date, DayChunk) %>%
  summarise(MedOzon=median(Ozon))
```

Comment: I am trying to make your solution work, but sadly it wont. What I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: Works fine for me. Be specific about exactly what is not working. The example above runs fine.

Comment: I believe your group_by needs to also incorporate the date along with DayChunk, otherwise your summary is 3 elements long and not 3 per day for the length of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the function seq.POSIXt. There are options to specify the start and stop intervals. This function is designed to create sequences of time. For your problem:

```
myseq<-seq(ISOdate(2010,01,01, 00, 00, 00, tz="GMT"), to=ISOdate(2016,01,05), by = "8 hour")
```

Use the ISOdate functions to set the start and stop times.  If you are going to be working much with times, I suggest researching the function strptime and the POSIXlt/ct time classes.
Now with the breaks defined and assuming you have a column in your dataframe (Datum_Ozon) named "datetime", then use "cut" to group/subset your data.

```
Datum_Ozon$datetime<-as.POSIXct(paste(as.character(Datum_Ozon$date),
     as.character(Datum_Ozon$time)), "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M", tz="GMT" )

library(dplyr)
summarize(group_by(Datum_Ozon, cut(Datum_Ozon$datetime, myseq)), mean(Ozon))
```

Comment: When I am using your solution, the second step returns into: Error in 1:intervalCnt : argument of length 0 Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: Ok, made some edits above.  myseq was starting at noon and not midnight.  All times have been set to GMT.  The newly added datetime column is now POSIXct class.  Everything should now be consistent and error free.  If not let me know.

Comment: @ Dave2e, thank you, this also worked for me. Now I have a df of 5.477 x2. The next step would be to draw a grapg with the DOY (1...365). Each DOY should represent the mean of every DOY (1...365) of the time series.  Any idea? Also, how do I set the GMT to GMT +1?

Comment: See help for "time zones" and use OlsonNames() for a list of the available time zone codes.  Pick the one where you live and substitute it in above.  Plotting at this point is simple, you have new data frame with datetime as one column and mean as the second column so plot() should work.  For 0-365 days at the "julian" command for the x labels.

Comment: I got how to mange the timezone. But if I plot, it plots of course the 5477 entries on the x-axis and what I want to show, is a graph (normal distribution) of the ozone at a line plot of 365 days (which are based on the five years measurement). So how can I get it?

Comment: I am not completely sure what you request is.  To plot a histogram, use the "hist" command on the mean column.  If you what a seperate histogram for each year, then create a new myseq with 1 year as the interval and use this to subset your data for each year.  If you need more help, it might be best to close this question and ask a new one.  Provide the data you wish to plot and what code you have tried.