# How to convert weather data recorded at 15 minutes interval to hourly data?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, aggregate, posixct

Our weather station recorded temperature data at 15 minutes interval. I'd like to calculate hourly `min`imum, daily `max`imum and daily `mean` temperatures. How can I do this in R programming language, preferably in `dplyr` syntax?

My data looks like this

```
                   date temperature
1   2014-05-26 11:45:00        25.0
2   2014-05-26 12:00:00        25.2
3   2014-05-26 12:15:00        25.3
4   2014-05-26 12:30:00        25.1
5   2014-05-26 12:45:00        25.4
[...]
96  2014-05-27 11:30:00        26.3
97  2014-05-27 11:45:00        25.7
98  2014-05-27 12:00:00        24.9
99  2014-05-27 12:15:00        24.9
100 2014-05-27 12:30:00        26.0
```

Here is the reproducible example. The `dput` function changes date format and mdy_hm won't parse it properly. I think this the reason some of the answers are not working for me.

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1401104700, 1401105600, 1401106500, 
1401107400, 1401108300, 1401109200, 1401110100, 1401111000, 1401111900, 
1401112800, 1401113700, 1401114600, 1401115500, 1401116400, 1401117300, 
1401118200, 1401119100, 1401120000, 1401120900, 1401121800, 1401122700, 
1401123600, 1401124500, 1401125400, 1401126300, 1401127200, 1401128100, 
1401129000, 1401129900, 1401130800, 1401131700, 1401132600, 1401133500, 
1401134400, 1401135300, 1401136200, 1401137100, 1401138000, 1401138900, 
1401139800, 1401140700, 1401141600, 1401142500, 1401143400, 1401144300, 
1401145200, 1401146100, 1401147000, 1401147900, 1401148800, 1401149700, 
1401150600, 1401151500, 1401152400, 1401153300, 1401154200, 1401155100, 
1401156000, 1401156900, 1401157800, 1401158700, 1401159600, 1401160500, 
1401161400, 1401162300, 1401163200, 1401164100, 1401165000, 1401165900, 
1401166800, 1401167700, 1401168600, 1401169500, 1401170400, 1401171300, 
1401172200, 1401173100, 1401174000, 1401174900, 1401175800, 1401176700, 
1401177600, 1401178500, 1401179400, 1401180300, 1401181200, 1401182100, 
1401183000, 1401183900, 1401184800, 1401185700, 1401186600, 1401187500, 
1401188400, 1401189300, 1401190200, 1401191100, 1401192000, 1401192900, 
1401193800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    temperature = c(25, 25.2, 25.3, 25.1, 25.4, 26, 25.9, 25.6, 
    26.8, 27.8, 26.8, 26, 26, 26.3, 27, 27, 26.2, 25.8, 24.9, 
    25.1, 26.3, 25.6, 25.3, 25.2, 25.1, 24.8, 24.7, 24, 23, 22.7, 
    22.5, 22.5, 22.2, 21.9, 21.5, 21.1, 20.8, 20.5, 20.3, 20.3, 
    20.2, 20, 19.8, 19.6, 19.2, 19.1, 19.1, 18.9, 18.8, 18.6, 
    18.3, 18.2, 18.2, 18.2, 18.1, 17.9, 17.8, 17.7, 17.8, 18, 
    18.1, 18, 18.1, 18.6, 18.7, 18.5, 18.3, 18.1, 18.1, 18.6, 
    18.8, 18.6, 18.6, 18.3, 18.2, 18, 17.8, 18, 18.2, 18.9, 19.8, 
    19.6, 19.5, 19.7, 20.2, 21.5, 22.4, 23, 24, 23.3, 23.2, 23.7, 
    24.5, 24.8, 24.9, 26.3, 25.7, 24.9, 24.9, 26)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df$date = as.POSIXct(df$date)
```

I used the following code to convert data recorded at 15 minutes to *daily*, but I'd like to change to *hourly*.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
   group_by(date = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%       # how to group by hour?
    summarise(min_temp = min(temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
              max_temp = max(temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
              mean_temp = mean(temperature, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
              ungroup()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778233/calculating-the-median-of-a-time-series-by-8-every-8-hours/36778623#36778623

Comment: Problem here is to parse AM/PM based on your locale. What does `format(Sys.Date(), "%p")` return?

Comment: @Ric running `df %>%
  format(Sys.Date(), "%p")
` returns `Error in Ops.Date(del, by) : / not defined for "Date" objects`. I am attaching reproducible example but dput function changes date format and mdy_hm won't parse it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach with `round_date` to get hourly grouping. <strike>Using toy data.</strike>

<strike>(... to make sure your *date* is of class `date` use: `df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")`)</strike>

EDIT, using posted `df`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(format(round_date(date, "hour"), "%H:%M") == 
                                 format(date, "%H:%M"))) %>% 
  summarize(date = unique(format(date, "%m/%d/%Y %I:00 %p")), 
            max_temperature = max(temperature), 
            min_temerature = min(temperature), 
            mean_temperature = mean(temperature)) %>% 
  select(-grp)
# A tibble: 26 × 4
   date                max_temperature min_temerature mean_temperature
   <chr>                         <dbl>          <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 05/26/2014 11:00 AM            25             25               25  
 2 05/26/2014 12:00 PM            25.4           25.1             25.2
 3 05/26/2014 01:00 PM            26.8           25.6             26.1
 4 05/26/2014 02:00 PM            27.8           26               26.6
 5 05/26/2014 03:00 PM            27             26.2             26.6
 6 05/26/2014 04:00 PM            26.3           24.9             25.5
 7 05/26/2014 05:00 PM            25.6           25.1             25.3
 8 05/26/2014 06:00 PM            24.8           23               24.1
 9 05/26/2014 07:00 PM            22.7           22.2             22.5
10 05/26/2014 08:00 PM            21.9           20.8             21.3
# … with 16 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

If you actually want a summarized table over all hours add one additional `summarize`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(format(round_date(date, "hour"), "%H:%M") == 
                                 format(date, "%H:%M"))) %>% 
  summarize(Hour = unique(format(date, "%H:00")), 
            max_temperature = max(temperature), 
            min_temperature = min(temperature), 
            mean_temperature = mean(temperature)) %>% 
  select(-grp) %>% 
  summarize(across(ends_with("temperature"), mean), .by = Hour) %>%
  arrange(Hour)
# A tibble: 24 × 4
   Hour  max_temperature min_temperature mean_temperature
   <chr>           <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 00:00            18.6            18.2             18.3
 2 01:00            18.2            17.8             18  
 3 02:00            18.1            17.7             17.9
 4 03:00            18.7            18               18.4
 5 04:00            18.5            18.1             18.2
 6 05:00            18.8            18.6             18.7
 7 06:00            18.3            17.8             18.1
 8 07:00            19.8            18               18.7
 9 08:00            20.2            19.5             19.8
10 09:00            24              21.5             22.7
# … with 14 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thanks. This code actually works but I end up getting `16128` hours. My data is huge. Ideally I should get 12 hours each day. When I grouped by date to group by day as well `group_by(grp = cumsum(format(round_date(date, "hour"), "%H:%M") == 
                           format(date, "%H:%M", date))) %>% `  I get an error `Error in `group_by()`:
! Problem adding computed columns.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `grp = cumsum(...)`.
Caused by error in `as.POSIXlt.POSIXct()`:
! invalid 'tz' value`

Comment: The problem exists with `df$date <- df$date <- force_tz(as.POSIXct(df$date, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"), tz = "America/New_York")`

Comment: @Ahsk I ran the code with your posted data, works right away. You might want to post an expected result because I don't know what you mean by "I end up getting 16128 hours". Where do you get that number from?

Comment: @Ahsk Do you want to summarize each hour per day to a grand total mean per hour over all days?

Comment: The edited answer works. I was just getting grp column with no date information, so it was hard to summarise by other variables. I wanted hourly summary for each day/date. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional grouping variable using `lubridate::hour`, e.g.

```r
> '4/20/2017 7:30 PM' |> 
+     strptime(format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p', tz = 'UTC') |> 
+     lubridate::hour()
[1] 19
```

(make sure the timezone is correct, just in case)

Comment: Am I running this code right? I get strange output running this `df <-  strptime(df$date, format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p', tz = 'UTC') %>%
   lubridate::hour()`

Comment: No-no, add another grouping variable the same way you added date, e.g. `df |> rename(datetime = date) |> group_by(date = lubridate::as_date(datetime), hour = lubridate::hour(datetime)) |> summarise(<...>)`. Don't do `df$date = as.POSIXct(df$date)` before though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

1. convert date to a datetime object with `lubridate`.
2. extract hour from datetime object.
3. group by hour and summarize.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(
  date = c('4/20/2017 1:40 PM', '4/20/2017 1:45 PM',
           '4/20/2017 6:45 PM', '4/20/2017 7:45 PM'),
  temperature = c(14.5, 14.8, 19, 21.0)
)

# create date time, hour
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    datetime = parse_date_time(df$date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p'),
    hour = lubridate::hour(datetime))

# group by hour
df %>%
  group_by(hour) %>%
  summarise(min_temp = min(temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
            max_temp = max(temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
            mean_temp = mean(temperature, na.rm = TRUE))
```

returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
   hour min_temp max_temp mean_temp
  <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1    13     14.5     14.8      14.6
2    18     19       19        19  
3    19     21       21        21
```

Comment: If more than one date, will summarise incorrectly. UPD: or maybe not - depending on what OP needs

Comment: I am getting issues with data parsing. Running the above code gives an error `Warning message:
Problem while computing `datetime = parse_date_time(df$date, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p")`.
ℹ All formats failed to parse. No formats found. `

Comment: Your posted example doesn't contain any hour/minute/seconds information, only dates. It also doesn't match your first screenshot, which I based my answer off of.

Comment: @DmitryZotikov OP asked to group by hour

Answer (score 0):

We here first transform to datetime format with `mdy_hm()` function. then
2. after calculating the difference to the next row we apply `cumsum()`
3. We create hours with `ceiling(diff/60)` then we use the existing code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(date = mdy_hm(date),
         diff = cumsum(as.numeric(difftime(date,lag(date, default = date[1]), units = "mins"))),
         hour = ceiling(diff / 60)) %>%
  group_by(hour) %>%
  summarise(min_temp = min(temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
            max_temp = max(temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
            mean_temp = mean(temperature, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()


  hour min_temp max_temp mean_temp
  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1     0     14.5     14.5      14.5
2     1     14.8     19.1      16.8
3     2     20.2     21.8      21.3
4     3     22.4     25.6      24.1
5     4     24.7     26.8      25.8
6     5     24.1     25.3      24.8
7     6     23       26.3      24.5
8     7     24.6     26.1      25.4
9     8     24.7     27.7      26.2
```

data

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("4/20/2017 1:30 PM", "4/20/2017 1:45 PM", 
"4/20/2017 2:00 PM", "4/20/2017 2:15 PM", "4/20/2017 2:30 PM", 
"4/20/2017 2:45 PM", "4/20/2017 3:00 PM", "4/20/2017 3:15 PM", 
"4/20/2017 3:30 PM", "4/20/2017 3:45 PM", "4/20/2017 4:00 PM", 
"4/20/2017 4:15 PM", "4/20/2017 4:30 PM", "4/20/2017 4:45 PM", 
"4/20/2017 5:00 PM", "4/20/2017 5:15 PM", "4/20/2017 5:30 PM", 
"4/20/2017 5:45 PM", "4/20/2017 6:00 PM", "4/20/2017 6:15 PM", 
"4/20/2017 6:30 PM", "4/20/2017 6:45 PM", "4/20/2017 7:00 PM", 
"4/20/2017 7:15 PM", "4/20/2017 7:30 PM", "4/20/2017 7:45 PM", 
"4/20/2017 8:00 PM", "4/20/2017 8:15 PM", "4/20/2017 8:30 PM", 
"4/20/2017 8:45 PM", "4/20/2017 9:00 PM", "4/20/2017 9:15 PM", 
"4/20/2017 9:30 PM"), temperature = c(14.5, 14.8, 15.8, 17.3, 
19.1, 20.2, 21.4, 21.8, 21.7, 22.4, 23.2, 25.3, 25.6, 26.5, 26.8, 
24.7, 25.2, 25, 25.3, 24.7, 24.1, 23, 23.1, 25.6, 26.3, 26.1, 
25.8, 25.2, 24.6, 24.7, 25.6, 26.8, 27.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-33L))
```

Comment: If more than one date, will summarise incorrectly. UPD: or maybe not - depending on what OP needs

Comment: Correct, but then we could group by day also. So this should be not problem?

Comment: Yeah, but @Ahsk may want across-day summary, then this grouping would be correct

Comment: Ok. In that case we would need another solution. But I think this is doable also. Let's see what OP want?!

Comment: Running the above code give me just none line `df`. I think the problem might be due to data parsing issues. I get `NA` in hour column and get the following error `Warning message:                                                                              
Problem while computing `date = mdy_hm(date)`.
ℹ All formats failed to parse. No formats found. `

Answer (score 0):

Using a non-tidyvert approach we can use `by` with `"POSIXct"` converted to `"Date"` as `INDICES=` which splits the data by dates into a list-like object. Then we can `aggregate`  on `strftime`d `%H`ours to get the hourly `min`imums. Finally just `data.frame` the `min` of `h_mins` as well as the daily `max` and `min`, and `rbind` the thing.

```
by(df, as.Date(df$date), \(x) {
  h_mins <- aggregate(temperature ~ strftime(x$date, '%H'), x, min)[, 'temperature']
  data.frame(min_temp=min(h_mins), max_temp=max(x$temperature), mean_temp=mean(x$temperature))
}) |> do.call(what=rbind)
#            min_temp max_temp mean_temp
# 2017-04-20 12.09854 19.94601  17.01504
# 2017-04-21 12.09854 19.94601  17.01504
# 2017-04-22 12.09854 19.94601  17.01504
```

**Note:** I used the data below to have more days available. This also works with your `dput`, but you need to `df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date)` since you have `"POSIXct"` format.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- data.frame(
  date=seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct('2017-04-20', tz='GMT'), as.POSIXct('2017-04-22 23:45', tz='GMT'), by='15 mins'),
  temperature=dnorm(seq.int(-1, 1, length.out=96))*.5e2
)
```

Comment: your code out put is daily summary. There are 12 hours in a day, so I should get 12 max, mean, min values for each day? I get the same output running my own code in the question `df %>%
   group_by(date = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%       # how to group by hour?
    summarise(min_temp = min(temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
              max_temp = max(temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
              mean_temp = mean(temperature, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
              ungroup()`

Comment: @Ahsk Please edit your question by adding expected output and report back.